# How can I create a Layer on an Image?

Tags: asp.net, image, web, layer

How can I create a Layer on an Image, or Image on another Image?
because it doesn't let me do that, only layer near the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a transparent png or gif for the transparent layer and use position:absolute or position:relative in your style or css to place it over the first layer.

Answer (score 1):

You choices come down to two strategies:

**1) Composite them on the client**, in the browser, by overlaying a mostly-transparent image over the main one. This is probably simpler, and requires html and css skills, but will be the same technique regardless of if the server running Asp.net or not. But it has the drawback that someone who knows what they are doing can pull out the complete image from behind the overlay. This may or may not be something that you care about.

**2) Composite them on the server.** You can do this in .Net using variations [on this technique](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020924.htm). It will use more server CPU, but only the finished image is sent to the client. It's more appropriate where the image is different for every user, or you don't want to send the image without the overlay.